# dplyr: swap end date with start date if end date is less than start date

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with start and end dates, and I am calculating the difference in time between them using the `difftime` function. However, some of my start dates are greater than my end dates, which results in a negative time difference. I need to swap the start date for the end date and vice versa when this happens. How can I do this?

Here is an example data frame:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
colnames(df1)[1:3] <- c('date_start','date_end','diff')
df1$date_start <- c(as.Date('2004-11-09'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                    as.Date('1992-09-01'))
df1$date_end <- c(as.Date('2005-11-09'),
                    as.Date('2010-12-31'),
                    as.Date('2006-10-31'))
df1$diff <- difftime(df1$date_end,df1$date_start)
df1
```

The correct data frame should look like this (with the start and end dates swapped in the second row):

```r
  date_start   date_end      diff
1 2004-11-09 2005-11-09  365 days
2 2010-12-31 2020-01-01 3288 days
3 1992-09-01 2006-10-31 5173 days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- df1 |> 
  transform(date_start = pmin(date_start, date_end),
            date_end   = pmax(date_start, date_end))
```

(`base::transform` is similar to `dplyr::mutate`, but one difference is that each term is calculated based on the incoming data, not on "the data as it exists after modifications to that point." The code would not work like this with `mutate` since `date_start` would be overwritten after the first step.)

Answer (score 0):

To swap the start and end dates in cases where the start date is greater than the end date, you can use conditional logic.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
colnames(df1)[1:3] <- c('date_start', 'date_end', 'diff')
df1$date_start <- c(as.Date('2004-11-09'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                    as.Date('1992-09-01'))
df1$date_end <- c(as.Date('2005-11-09'),
                  as.Date('2010-12-31'),
                  as.Date('2006-10-31'))

# Swap start and end dates when start > end
df1[df1$date_start > df1$date_end, c('date_start', 'date_end')] <- df1[df1$date_start > df1$date_end, c('date_end', 'date_start')]

df1$diff <- difftime(df1$date_end, df1$date_start)
   df1
  date_start   date_end      diff
1 2004-11-09 2005-11-09  365 days
2 2010-12-31 2020-01-01 3288 days
3 1992-09-01 2006-10-31 5173 days
```

This code checks if the date_start is greater than the date_end and swaps the values for those rows using indexing.